# Calculate a Linear Forecast without FORECAST.LINEAR

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a requirement that calls for Excel's FORECAST.LINEAR function, but the version of excel being used doesn't support that function (or the older FORECAST function.) How would I calculate an output like the sales forecast in the example below without the built-in function?

For this particular requirement, the client doesn't *require* the exact output of FORECAST.LINEAR. So if there's a simpler approach yielding a similar result, that would be great too.

[image]

Comment: use the original `FORECAST` function which still works in current versions as well.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner, I've updated my question a bit. This is actually an excel-compatible engine embedded in another piece of software, and doesn't have *any* version of the FORECAST functions.

Comment: do you have `SLOPE` and `INTERCEPT`?

Comment: Say, we do! Great thought. Let me see if I can make this work...

Comment: @JamesOrr You shoud tag Scott Craner using the @ symbol. He might not know that you want him to answer the answer the question

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for the tip, it worked perfectly. Please put in your comment as an answer so I can accept it! :)